# etcd nodes upgrade procedure requirements

Tags: etcd

what is the process to upgrade etcd nodes from 3.5 to 3.5.8.

I am following the steps below:

Download the required version Unzip the file Add binaries to the path Test the version.

Does adding binaries alone upgrade the version to the required release?

Comment: The good practice is to use your distribution package manager.